# Converting evtx log to csv error

Tags: csv, logparser

I am trying to convert and evtx log file to csv from log parser 2.2. I just want to copy all of the data into a csv.

```
LogParser "Select * INTO C:\Users\IBM_ADMI
N\Desktop\sample.csv FROM C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Event    
Logs\sample.evtx" -i:EVTX -o:csv
```

But I am getting the error below.

> Error: Syntax Error: extra token(s) after query: 'Logs\sample.evtx'

Please assist in solving this error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been a year but if you (or other people) still need it and for sake of reference, this is what I do:

```
LogParser "Select * INTO C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\sample.csv FROM 'C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Event Logs\sample.evtx'" -i:evt -o:csv
```

1. Correct input type is `evt`, not `evtx`.
2. If there is space in the `Event Logs` folder, enclose with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was due to the extra space in between the folder name Event Logs. Changed the folder name to a single workd and it worked.

Comment: You could also have enclosed the path within single quote characters.

Comment: I tried enclosing the whole path with single quote char but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert .evtx file to .csv than you can read from this .csv file.
like this .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T6ev.png)

```
    //String command = "powershell.exe  your command";

            //called the PowerShell from java code
```

String command = "powershell.exe   Get-WinEvent -Path C:\windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx | Export-Csv system.csv";
File seys = new File("system.csv");
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Comment: note: above the codes converted your .evtx file to your program directory which is you runned your program.